# Can't scroll website in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I can't scroll my website in firefox. It just works as intended with other browsers such as Chrome, Safari and Internet explorer.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this? Is this problem caused by a bug in firefox or is my code incompatible in some way?
http://v14ewoude.helenparkhurst.net/portfolio.html

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: You have `body{overflow: hidden}`. Remove it.

Comment: if you need the overflow hidden, just make sure you do `overflow-x: hidden` but it looks as if your site doesn't need it at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, everything seems good except `overflow: hidden` on `body`.

I don't know why it is working on Chrome and other browsers, probably they fix this issue with their default parameters, but usually you don't use `overflow` parameter on `body`.

On Element inspector I tried removing it and it worked. Have a nice day :)